# count>=10? break : continue;

Tags: c, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

```c
while(1) {
    // other stuff

    // there's no code in the loop after the below statement:
    count>=10? break : continue; // error
}
```

Why does this statement give errors? Any help will be highly appreciated.

58  16  [Error] expected expression before 'break'

This is the error that the compiler gives.

Comment: For the same reason that `break + continue` fails: parts of an expression have to be expressions.

Comment: 'break' is not an expression.  Use an 'if'.

Comment: Also, it would be pointless even if it had worked. Just replace it with `if(count >= 10) break;` I expect that you have no code in the loop after that conditional operator. If you have, when do you expect that code to be executed? Choosing either `break` or `continue` makes that code unreachable.

Comment: The ternary operator expects two values or function calls of one type delimited by `:`. For example, you can write an expression like `return (count >= 10)? 78 : 54;`, but not `(count >= 10)? return 78 : return 54`

Comment: @TedLyngmo The `break/continue` might be inside another `if`, so the following code would get executed if the `if` isn't entered.

Comment: That's one reason why the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is expected. Welcome, may I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @interjay Yes, that's true. It'd be nice to see the full context.

Comment: @Ted , Thanks for your reply. Yes, there's no code after that statement but its a while(1) loop. So, this part is required for exiting the loop.

Comment: Just as a side note: You can even use expressions having a `void` type – like calling two different functions (but you need to make sure both expressions having the same type, i.e. if need be add a cast, see example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nY4sMEqsG)).

Comment: @TedLyngmo, In any case , its a wild guess that some high level languages do allow this kind of statements. Do you know any ?

Comment: No code after and within a while -> `if(condition) { break; }` – but if there's no code following anyway possibly a `for` loop might even be better alternative: `for(initialisation; count < 10; ++count)` – you just need to invert the comparison for...

Comment: In response to a couple of comments (Ivan Venkov, Aconcagua): It's not necessary for the second and third expressions to have the same type; they just have to have compatible type.  The compiler is happy to insert implicit conversions, if necessary, just like it is in any mixed-mode expression.  That is, `x ? 1 : 2.3` is as legal as `1 + 2.3`.

Comment: _"there's no code after that statement"_ -  then make it  `do { ... } while(count < 10);`

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this statement give errors ?

`?:` **is not** a *"short version of `if`"* as it is incorrectly described on many sites.
`?:` is not a statement, it is an operator.

An operator joins one, two or three operands to produce an expression. An expression is a piece of code that is computed and produces a value. A statement is a piece of code that does something. They are different things.

A statement can contain expressions. An expression cannot contain statements.

`break` and `continue` are statements. This is why the fragment `count >= 10 ? break : continue;` is not a valid statement and does not compile.

Use an `if` statement and it works:

```c
if (count >= 10) {
  break;
} else {
  continue;
}
```

Comment: Actually no `else` needed, could be written, too, a bit shorter as `if(count >= 10) { break; } continue;` – some consider it bad style having an `else` if the `if` makes it obsolete anyway due to `break/continue/return/...`, me personally won't argue about, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua The "rule" about `else` being bad style is arguable. The code should express the intent, complying to some artificial rules comes on the second place. Most of the times, indeed, an `else` is not needed or the code is cleaner without it. There are situations when the `else` makes the code cleaner. Never mind. The original code contains an `else` and without knowing the context we cannot decide that the `else` is not needed. Maybe the `then` branch is not needed. Maybe both are needed. Who knows? Only the author of the original code.

Comment: Well, we can at least clearly decide that the raw `else` (not speaking of the entire branch) is never *needed* – still having it for whatever reasons is another issue. Why the ternary operator at all? Brevity probably. And the dropped else is shorter, my main reason for coming up with the other variant...

Answer (score 0):

As it follows from the error message

```
58 16 [Error] expected expression before 'break'
```

in this statement with the conditional operator

```
count>=10? break : continue;
```

the compiler expects expressions instead of the statements `break` and `continue`.

According to the C Standard the conditional operator is defined the following way

```
logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

As you can see it includes three expressions.

Instead of using the conditional operator you could use the if-else statement the following way

```
if ( count>=10 )
{ 
    break;
}
else
{ 
    continue;
}
```

But in any case this construction with `break` and `continue` statements looks badly.

It seems you should move the condition `count>=10`  in the loop statement that is used. Or it will be enough to write

```
if ( count>=10 )
{ 
    break;
}
```

without the else part of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

[Conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other):

> `a ? b : c` - if `a` is logically `true` (does not evaluate to zero) then evaluate **expression** `b`, otherwise evaluate **expression** `c`

Neither `break` nor `continue` are expressions. They are statements and can't be used with the conditional operator.

Furthermore, `continue` as the last statement in your loop is pointless.

What you need is simply:

```c
while(1) {
    // other stuff

    if(count >= 10) break;
}
```

or even simpler:

```c
do {
    // other stuff
} while(count < 10);
```